# Make a gridview image onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have a gridview and have an image column in it. It works without a problem but I need something more. I want to make the clicked image bigger and make screen focus on it. Actually what I have now is making this thing when images are not in  gridview but like I said I need images in my gridview. Here is my css (I want to write my css too since it makes the focusing):

```
#overlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.7;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 70) !important;
        display: none;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #overlayContent {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #contentGallery {
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    #imgBig, #imgSmall {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

My gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewEvents" CssClass="mGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceEvents">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Araç">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#GetPlate(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("CarId"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sürücü">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#GetDriverId(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("DriverId"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alış KM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="overlayContent">
                    <img id="imgBig" src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div id="grid">
                    <img id="imgSmall" onclick="Tiklandi()" alt="" src='<%#Eval("FirstKmImage") %>' />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="İade KM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="ImageLast" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("LastKmImage") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alış Tarih">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("FirstDate") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="İade Tarih">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("LastDate") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Güzergah">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Guzergah") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="İş Durumu">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#IsDurumu(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Done")))%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my js code:

```
function Tiklandi() {
        $("#imgBig").attr("src", $(this).prop('src'));
        $("#overlay").show('slow');
        $("#overlayContent").show('slow');
    }
```

How can I make my js code to make this kind of proccess in a gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add class on the `<img>` element.

```
<asp:Image ID="ImageLast" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("LastKmImage") %>' runat="server" class="Tiklandi" />
```

And bind the click event handler to the class

```
$('.Tiklandi').click(function() {
        $("#imgBig").attr("src", $(this).prop('src'));
        $("#overlay").show('slow');
        $("#overlayContent").show('slow');
    })
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: make sure you put the event handler inside `$(document).ready` and i recommend you not to put `overlayContent` inside `asp:GridView` because it will be created multiple times as many as data number.